# Team Foundation Server: Building to a fixed Location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to use Team Foundation Build Services to put the lastest Build of a Build Definition to a fixed UNC File Path.

Normaly the Build Definition adds some Variables like Date or Build Number into the Path to make it unique.
I tried to delete them in my Definition to get a fixed path, but the Build failed with the Error that the Destination already exists on the Server.

Why do I want to Build to a fixed location:
I want to do that so the Team testing my Application has a fixed location to the latest Build, and can e.g. put a Shortcut on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to have fixed drop location as root folder with Build number added to the path. This would help you to distinguish different build versions executed from a build definition. If you have fixed location, then what would you do if you want to get previously executed build binaries in case if latest build breaks?

If you still want to go with fixed location, then you could modify the build process template to delete the fixed folder during the build process so that you wont get destination already exist errors.